# How would I find the smallest number in an array and remove it then adding all the numbers together

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find the smallest number in an array either multidimensional array or one dimensional array. Then remove the number and add all the numbers together. I am able to find the smallest number using the min method and add them together using the sum method. However I do not know how to remove the outcome from the min method.

```
public void Calculatepredictionbtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int firstymark1 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark1.Text);
    int firstymark2 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark2.Text);
    int firstymark3 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark3.Text);
    int firstymark4 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark4.Text);
    int firstymark5 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark5.Text);
    int firstymark6 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark6.Text);
    int firstymark7 = Int32.Parse(firsty_mark7.Text);
    int secondymark = Int32.Parse(secondy_mark1.Text);
    int[] modules = new int[] { firstymark1, firstymark2, firstymark3, firstymark4,
                                firstymark5, firstymark6, firstymark7 };
    int reduction = modules.Min();
    ///dont know how to remove the number 
    int arrayadded = modules.Sum();
}
```

Comment: There are better ways to do it (if you are really looking for performance but it does not seem the case) but...you already have the sum and the minimum. You just need to use "-". BTW you do not need to create 7 local variables, why don't you directly populate the array?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to remove a value it would be better to use a [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of array, because resizing arrays is expensive. By using `List` you have the `Remove` method also:

```
List<int> modules =  new List<int>(){ firstymark1, firstymark2, firstymark3, firstymark4,
                                      firstymark5, firstymark6, firstymark7 };
int reduction = modules.Min();
modules.Remove(reduction);
int arrayadded = modules.Sum();
```